# asp.net ajax updatepanel asyncPostBackTrigger refreshes pages

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Im really getting angry about this nonsense error. i have a ultra simple page like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ajax.aspx.cs" Inherits="tebimir.ajax" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">    </asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my button click event:

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

everytime i click on button1 page gets refreshed?! why? should not it be an async postpack?

Comment: do you have anything else on the page or just this code?

Comment: No thats all the code i have

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your update panel will already cause an ajax postback and you do not need to add the button as an AsyncPostBackTrigger.

You can use the AsyncPostBackTrigger to make a button outside of the panel cause the UpdatePanel to postback.

Remove the following and try again:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: I removed the trigger nothing changed